# SQL calculation issue

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am trying to find the cost per category by joining two tables

I have wrote this query, but it seems to place the same resulting value for all categories.

```
SELECT category,
      (select sum(count(partid) * p.cost) 
       from PARTS p join order_line o using (part_id) 
       group by category, p.cost)
from parts p join order_line o using (part_id)
group by category
```

Table structure:

```
Parts:PartID#,description,manu_date,manu_id,cost,retai,discount,category
Order_line: Order#,item#,PartID,manu_id,unitprice,quantity
```

What I am trying to accomplish is i want to times the cost per parts table, with the count of (quantity*partid) in the order_line table to find out which category has the highest cost.

I am using oracle 11g

Comment: Post some sample data and the expected result.  Just the fields that are used in your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your subquery isn't correlated with the embedding sql, therefore its result is the same for each category.

You do not need to weigh the part costs with the number of orders, this will happen implicitly through the join:

```
    SELECT category
         , sum (p.cost * o.quantity)
      FROM parts p
      JOIN order_line o USING (partid)
  GROUP BY category
         ;
```